# Java EE How do you use an EntityManager with Mongo?

Tags: mongodb, java-ee-6, entitymanager

I"m trying to create a Java EE project using a mongo database. I am unable to find any good working examples.How do you correctly set up JPA for the project?

Answer (score 1):

Java EE 6 (or in JPA 2.0 as an part of it) does not have any defined support for MongoDB or for NoSQL databases in general.

That's why how it is done depends fully from JPA provider implementation. If you use EclipseLink, maybe you can try to follow example given in [this](http://java-persistence-performance.blogspot.de/2012/04/eclipselink-jpa-supports-mongodb.html) blog post and present further questions about what exactly is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Hey you should at least check out Arun Gupta's blog post on this at https://blogs.oracle.com/arungupta/entry/java_ee_6_and_nosql. Gupta is the Oracle Java EE Evangelist and this entry covers using EclipseLink for a JPA connection to MongoDB and deploying to Glassfish. If you search his blog, there is also an earlier entry on how to use the Java driver included with MongoDB in a Java EE project. I haven't tried the example with an EntityManager but am thinking about doing so.